# Ordinal 241 could not be located

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I am using Anaconda3-5.3.0-Windows-x86_64 release and experienced the following problem:

While running import command (e.g. - import numpy as np), from Jupyter notebook,  I receive the following error -

> The ordinal 241 could not be located in the dynamic link library path:\mkl_intel_thread.dll>

Where 'path' is the path to anaconda directory in my Win10 PC.

I tried the following in order to overcome this issue -

- Reinstall anaconda from scratch
- Update the .dll to latest one
- Update Win10 path to search the right folders

Unfortunately - non of the above methods worked for me.

Can someone offer some solution / new ideas to check?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I came to a conclusion that there is a problem with adaptation of this Anaconda version with my Win 8.1.

So, I downgraded Anaconda version to Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64 and that solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting the solution.  I would have never figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with similar issue, please see this post:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed

It solved the issue for me. Turned out that there are duplicate libs in /Windows/System32 folder which are incompatible with Anaconda. Renaming then solved the issue and also enabled GPU to work on my Tensorflow installation.